# Why is react text input not changing when useState array element changes?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

```
function Example() {
    const [strings, setStrings] = useState(["hi","yo"]);

    return (
      <div>
         <input name='foo' type="text" value={strings[0]}  onChange={setElement} />
      </div>
    );

    function setElement(e){
        let copyStrings = strings; 
        copyStrings[0] = e.target.value; 
        setStrings(copyStrings)
    }
 }
```

When I type a key in the text input box, I can see in react devtools that the state for the useState hook is updated to include that key, but the text displayed in the input doesn't change. Why is this and how do I fix it?
I have an array of values that I want the user to be able to edit in input controls.

Comment: Arrays are stored as references in Javascript. So by doing `let copyStrings = strings;`, both `copyStrings` and `strings` are referring to literally the same thing. So when you subsequently do `copyStrings[0] = e.target.value;` you're changing `strings` too, i.e. directly mutating the state, which you shouldn't do in react. Make a copy first, e.g. using the spread operator: `let copyStrings = [...strings];` Not saying that'll fix your error, but just a point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`let copyStrings = strings` is a shallow copy. You are copying the reference to the array

you need to do a deep copy. There are a few options:

`let copyStrings = [...strings]; //works with arrays`
or 
`let copyStirngs = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(strings)); // works with objects as well`

Comment: Thanks, that works.  I am curious why it doesn't work using the array reference.

Comment: because you didn't change the state. the state point to the array. After you modified the array the state is still pointing to the same place in memory (which now holds a different value). Therefore, React didn't re-render